# Ensure that column names in output retain original variable names, instead of using arbitrary X1, X2, etc

Tags: r, simulation

Is there a more elegant way to ensure that `colnames(output)` of a `output` R dataframe retains the original column variable names in the referenced sample dataset `data`? So that I can eliminate the 2 `gsub()` lines of code, which rename my column names back to my original variable names. My R code, which can be run, is as follows

```
library(mvtnorm)
library(tidyverse)
muvec = apply(data, 2, mean) #data is passed as R dataframe
sigma = cov(data)
df = 10
n = 10
output <- as.data.frame(
        lapply(1:n, function(x) rep(muvec, each=10) + rmvt(10, sigma=sigma, df=df))) %>%
        select (sort(names(.)))
#looped function output assigns arbitrary variable names X1 and X2, instead of original variable names apple and pear
colnames(output) = gsub("X1", "apple", colnames(output))
colnames(output) = gsub("X2", "pear", colnames(output))
print(output)
```

`data` as follows

```
+-------+-------+
| apple | pear  |
+-------+-------+
|  0.18 |  0.05 |
|  0.22 |  0.03 |
|  0.21 |  0.03 |
|  0.11 |     0 |
|  0.15 |  0.03 |
|  0.13 |  0.01 |
|  0.03 |  0.01 |
|     0 |     0 |
| -0.06 | -0.01 |
| -0.09 | -0.02 |
+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way that I can think of is creating a function with `rmvt` which takes an additional argument to decide whether column names should be assigned based on the input (*i.e.* `sigma`) or not. If `TRUE`, before returning the results of `rmvt` function, it assigns the original names. See below (I used `airquality` dataset to make a reproducible example);

```r
library(mvtnorm)
library(dplyr)

dat <- na.omit(datasets::airquality)[1:2,1:2]

muvec = apply(dat, 2, mean) #data is passed as R dataframe
sigma = cov(dat)
df = 10
n = 2

rmvt.names <- function(n, sigma = diag(2), df = 1, delta = rep(0, nrow(sigma)),
                       type = c("shifted", "Kshirsagar"), names = FALSE){
  out <- rmvt(n, sigma, df, delta, type)
  if (names) { colnames(out) <- colnames(sigma) }
  return(out)
}

lapply(1:n, function(x) 
            rep(muvec, each=10) + rmvt.names(10, sigma=sigma, df=df, names = T)) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  select (sort(names(.)))

#>       Ozone  Ozone.1    Solar.R  Solar.R.1
#> 1  37.47822 45.06226 139.286427 248.496571
#> 2  40.59224 42.78024 184.128243 215.635423
#> 3  33.03107 35.89953  75.247397 116.553211
#> 4  28.07207 28.48342   3.837864   9.761237
#> 5  38.15097 39.46869 148.974039 167.949166
#> 6  44.04143 42.68460 233.796536 214.258203
#> 7  36.54224 40.53313 125.808217 183.277053
#> 8  37.37606 38.77892 137.815314 158.016502
#> 9  43.99939 37.11836 233.191196 134.104332
#> 10 37.63792 32.28113 141.586044  64.448253
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>